# Add highlight effect to the UIButton that created by PaintCode code

Tags: swift, uibutton, paintcode

I have made a button by using PaintCodes code:

```
class AddIconView: OUIButton {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        AddIcon.draw(frame: rect)
   }
}
```

Then I add its class to a UIButton. The problem is, the button is not highlighted anymore after touch it, what is the best way to add a highlight to it? 
for example for this button:

```
@IBOutlet weak var addButton: AddIconView!
```

Thank you so much for your help in advance

Edit:

I created a custom class for it:

```
class OUIButton: UIButton {
override var isHighlighted: Bool {
    get {
        return super.isHighlighted
    }
    set {
        if newValue {
            backgroundColor = .green
        }
        else {
            backgroundColor = .blue
        }
        super.isHighlighted = newValue
    }
 }}
```

For the test, I added a blue and green color. With this code, when I touch the button the background will become and stay blue. 
I want it to change only when it is touched and after release, it comes back to the normal state, exactly like a normal UIbutton

Answer (score 0):

It's solved, here is the code for anyone who want to use:

```
class OUIButton: UIButton {
    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        get {
            return super.isHighlighted
        }
        set {
            if newValue {
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0, options:.curveEaseIn , animations: {
                self.alpha = 0.5
            }, completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0, options:.curveEaseOut , animations: {
                self.alpha = 1
            }, completion: nil)
        }
        super.isHighlighted = newValue
    }
}}
```